# Ordering coordinates c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to order a list of coordinates in c++, but it's not working.
i'm using c++ sort function, and first ordering the x values and then the y values

if n = 9 and the coordinates:

```
(2,2) (2,3) (1,2) (1,3) (2,1) (1,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,1)
```

the output should be:

```
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3 ,3)
```

But for some reason, it is:

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(2,3)
(3,2)
(3,3)
(3,1)
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    short x;
    short y;
} coord;

bool comparex( coord a, coord b){
    if(a.x < b.x)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool comparey(coord a, coord b){
    
    if(a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y){
        return 1;
    } else return 0;
}


int main(){
    
    
    short n;
    coord v[1001];
    
    while(cin >> n){
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            cin >> v[i].x;
            cin >> v[i].y;
        }
        
        sort(v+1, v+n, comparex);
        sort(v+1, v+n, comparey);
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            cout << v[i].x << ' ' << v[i].y << endl;
        }
                    
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting your loop from 1 to n? Shouldn't it be from 0 to n-1? then in sort from v to v+n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison is flawed:

```
bool comparey(coord a, coord b){
    
    if(a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y){
        return 1;
    } else return 0;
}
```

You always return `0` (should be `false`) when `a.x != b.x`. For example `comparey({0,1}, {1,1}) == false` but also `comparey({1,1},{0,1}) == false`.

You can use `std::pair` for the comparison:

```
bool comparey(coord a, coord b){
    return std::pair(a.x,a.y) < std::pair(b.x,b.y);
}
```

or use `std::tie` to avoid constructing the pairs:

```
bool comparey(coord a, coord b){
    return std::tie(a.x,a.y) < std::tie(b.x,b.y);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you have, it's highly confusing that a function called `comparey` doesn't just compare `y`

Comment: @AlanBirtles actually you are right. I have difficulties sometimes to rephrase an answer after understanding the question better, or to not rephrase it ;)

Answer (score 6):

`std::sort` isn't stable, use `stable_sort` or better just use a comparator that compares both elements at once:

```
sort(v+1, v+n, [](coord a, coord b)
{
  return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y));
});
```

This uses `std::tie` which creates a `std::tuple` which automatically has the expected behaviour when comparing a pair of elements.

Note that for `stable_sort` to work you need to change `comparey` to just compare `y` (as its name suggests it does):

```
bool comparey(coord a, coord b){
    return a.y < b.y;
}
```

Your current implementation doesn't provide a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) so can't be used as a comparator for either `sort` or `stable_sort`.

Answer (score 1):

This code invokes undefined behavior because your `comparey` does not satisfy the requirements of a [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) function. Specifically, the relation induced by defining `equiv(a, b)` to mean `!comparey(a, b) && !comparey(b, a)` is not transitive and therefore is not an equivalence relation.

Let `a` be `{1, 0}`.

Let `b` be `{2, 0}`.

Let `c` be `{1, 1}`.

Because `1 != 2`, the following are all `false`: `comparey(a, b)`, `comparey(b, a)`, `comparey(b, c)` and `comparey(c, b)`.

Therefore, `equiv(a, b)` and `equiv(b, c)` are both `true`. It should be the case that `equiv(a, c)` is `true` as well.

However, `comparey(a, c)` is `true`, not `false`. Therefore `equiv(a, c)` is `false`, when it should be `true`.

Therefore attempting to use `comparey` as a comparator for `sort` invokes undefined behavior.

---

Possible fixes:

Use a single comparison function that performs lexicographic comparison of elements.

```cpp
#include <tuple>

bool compare(coord a, coord b){
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
}
```

Make it so that `comparey` only compares the y coordinate, and use `stable_sort` so that applying `comparey` won't reorder elements that have the same y coordinate but different x coordinates.

```cpp
bool comparey(coord a, coordb){
    return a.y < b.y;
}

// In calling code:
#include <algorithm>

std::stable_sort(v+1, v+n, comparey);
```